# vscode react native exponent: how to login into my exponent account

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, exponent

I am trying to launch a debug session for my react-native app inside vscode (I have setup a debug configuration in the ./vscode/launch.json file which has been working fine until a few days).

1. I start the debug session from the debug dropdown and I select the "expo" configuration:

[image]

2. The output window shows that the debug session starts:

[image]

And it just stucks there...

But on the bottom-right corner, I get this message:

[image]

I thinks the debugger waits me to connect to this account. I cant seem to know how to connect to this account from within vscode. I can access all available commands from the react-native rools: no login prompt.

Has any one faced this problem? Is this something new with the exponent extension in vscode (I remember a few days ago, this problem was not there...)

Any suggestion would be really welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to terminal and log in expo using this command

`exp login`

Answer (score 1):

Install (globally) exp

```
npm install -g exp
```

and then use

```
exp login
```

as mentioned above and enter your expo.io credentials

Answer (score 0):

Now, in 2020 we use `expo login` to login and `expo logout` to logout